# Play Android camera shutter from Arduino Leonardo

Tags: android, arduino

I am trying to play the android camera shutter from Arduino Leonardo.
At first I tried to play the shutter from bluetooth keyboard. It worked fine by pressing F12 key.
But when I do it from Arduino Leonardo I send the F12 key to android (by using OTG cable) and does not play the shutter.
I already verified that keys go fine from arduino to android (i already tested it with other keys)

With a USB keyboard the F12 key has no effect (it does not play the shutter), but it works fine from bluetooth keyboard.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the solution in this forum:

[Multimedia keys in Arduino Leonardo](http://stefanjones.ca/blog/arduino-leonardo-remote-multimedia-keys/)

I tested it on arduino 1.0.5 and works OK.

To play the android shutter I use Remote.increase() function which corresponds to volume up.